# check coordinate exists between two points of line

Tags: javascript, coordinates, points

I have two points, lets say x1,y1 and x2,y2. 
and i have one more point x3,y3,
here is the question, i need to check is x3,y3 coordinate occurs in the line between x1,y1 and x2,y2 or not occurs in javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? This isn't as much a programming question as it is an algebra question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var point_a = [0, 0];
var point_b = [100, 200];
var coord = [50, 100];

function checkCoordinate(coord) {
    var slope = (point_b[1] - point_a[1]) / (point_b[0] - point_a[0]);
    var newSlope = (point_b[1] - coord[1]) / (point_b[0] - coord[0]);
    if (coord[0] > point_a[0] && coord[0] < point_b[0] && coord[1] > point_a[1] && coord[1] < point_b[1] && slope == newSlope) {
        alert('Yes! they are in the same line.');
    } else {
        alert('No :/');
    }
}
checkCoordinate(coord);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ug8k4/)

Comment: Hi Sergio,   Thanks for the Solution it works like hero.. and its simple too.

Comment: It doesn't work for [ 1, 4 ] [ 4, 1 ] [ 3, 2 ], the condition should be reversed for negative slope.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify x2,y2 do not (numerically) equal either of the end points:

You can create function to check this like (pseudocode):

```
IsNearZero(value) 
   if(abs(value) < tolerance) return true
   return false
```

So:
// Assuming a false return means (x2,y2) is NOT between them.

```
if((IsNearZero(x2-x1) && IsNearZero(y2-y1))
   return false 
if(IsNearZero(x2-x3) and IsNearZero(y2-y3))
   return false
```

Now check if (x2,y2) is between the points:

```
// Left Edge
if((x1 < x3) && (x2 < x1))
   return false
if((x3 < x1) && (x2 < x3))
   return false
// Bottom Edge
if((y1 < y3) && (y2 < y1))
   return false
if((y3 < y1) && (y2 < y3))
   return false
```

Do similar tests for the right and bottom edges...

Finally, take the cross product of the two lines:

The first segment:  (x1,y1,0) -> (x2,y2,0) --> (x2-x1, y2-y1,0)

The second segment: (x1,y1,0) -> (x3,y3,0) --> (x3-x1, y3-y1, 0)

if(not IsNearZero((x2-x1)*(y3-y1) - (y2-y1)*(x3-x1))
   return false

Now, return true...